# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: "Too many connections"

Tags: java

I have connection leak problem in my application , i see that number of connections creep up as some hours (requests ) pass by 
 finally they are all consumed and we get , we are using JDBC with defualt  tomcat 7  and default mysql 5.0

Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

This is the message we see under our server

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1110)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
```

And we are sure that we are closing all the DB Connections inside the java files

Utility class

```
public class DBConnection {

public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        String sURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sss";
        //String sURL="jdbc:mysql://192.xxx.2.s:3306/sss";
        String sUserName="root";
        String sPwd="";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL, sUserName,sPwd);
            return conn;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }


    public static void close(Connection con)
    {
        if (con != null)
        {
            try
            {
                con.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how i access the connection

```
public String adminLogin()
{
Connection dbConnection = null;

dbConnection = DBConnection.getDBConnection();

try
{
}
catch()
{

}

finally 
{
    DBConnection.close(dbConnection);
}
}
```

Could anybody plese let me know how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's crucial problem .... you should investigate this problem....

you can take log of which method is creating new connections by putting below code in your create connection method

```
    StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    System.out.println(  "create connection called from " + st[2] );
```

It may possible some code is  creating new connections in loop or your process is taking much time that before closing some old connection new connection is created and total connections increases..

in mysql workbench you can check total number of connection by this way 
[click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-client-connections.html)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has a confugurable [maximum number of connections allowed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), which is 100 (or 151, dependinng on version). Make sure you didn't configure a connection pool with a larger number of connections.

Comment: But strangely we are just 5 people acesing the application and i am sure that 100 connections would not be utilized .

Comment: But, do you have a connection pool?

Comment: No we dont have any connection pool , all just default ones (application currently in development stage)

Comment: Do we need tomcat connection pool ?? i guess that for 5 people not needed know , please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Hard to tell more without additional info, but you can track the creation of connections by monitoring the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on the database. It might help you debug when the connections are created and are they getting closed at all.